# CAML to show only Sites in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, caml

I need to view only the available sites defining a CAML-structure view in the Content and Structure Reports webpart.

I've tried using both Stramit Caml Viewer and U2U Caml Query Builder 2007 but they doesn't seem to support the objects I wan't to show (sites and subsites).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view then cant you use Power shell?

take a look at this Link which is uses powershell script to get data from web application.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47536/best-way-to-get-all-subsites